# I am currently working with Forge RCDB and MongoDB, but there is no data in Database and cost Breaddown, always show loading

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit

I am currently working with Forge RCDB and MongoDB,  but there is no data in Database and cost Breaddown, always show loading

Comment: What kind of MongoDB instance are you using? Local or cloud based like Atlas? And Did you load the sample data [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/resources/db/prod) into your database?

Comment: yes i have load the sample data

Comment: Then what kind of MongoDB instance are you using? Are you able to fetch the data with a client tool? Any error in your browser's console and/or backend?

Comment: there is no error in browser's console and backend                                            
Viewing.Extension.ExtensionManager.js:166 Viewing.Extension.ExtensionManager loaded
Viewing.Extension.Database.Table.js:106 Viewing.Extension.Database.Table loaded

Viewing.Extension.ContextMenu.js:85 Viewing.Extension.ContextMenu loaded
Viewing.Extension.Database.CostBreakdown.js:72 Viewing.Extension.Database.CostBreakdown loaded
Viewing.Extension.ViewerProperties.js:36 Viewing.Extension.ViewerProperties loaded

Comment: As was said in my previous comments confirm you can access the data in MongoDb with another client and loading shouldn't stick forever it'd time or error out eventually so watch out for front and backend console output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have followed the [README](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs#cloud-deployment) to import the sample data to your MongoDB properly and use models that are compatible with RCDB:

> 1/ You need to translate at least one model using your own Forge credentials, so it can be loaded by your app. In order to do that take a look at the step-by-step tutorial from the Model Derivative API to understand exactly what this is about.
>   If you want to skip that manual process you can use one of our live sample: https://models.autodesk.io. This app lets you put your credentials and translate a model on your behalf. Another option would be to deploy to heroku the Forge boiler plate sample #5. Make sure you deploy Project #5. This set up is more straightforward since it doesn't require any Cloud database or pre-translated models. It will let you upload, translate and manage further models as well.
>
> Once you have translated at least one model, take note of its URN, that's the base64 encoded objectId. You also need a model which has some "Material" properties to be compatible with forge-rcdb because it is expecting components with that property. You can use Engine.dwf placed in the resource/models directory of this project.

Just gave it a go myself and it worked well:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much .    i have resolve it .       when i set mongodb auth,     it work